# How can an array be an exponent?

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose there is a tuple `test = (1,2)` and I want to compute `10**test` which should equal `(10,100)`. But Python gives the error 
`unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'tuple'`

How do I do this in python?

Comment: That is not an array. That is a `tuple`

Answer (score 5):

Numpy arrays offer this feature:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test = np.array((1,2))
>>> test
array([1, 2])
>>> 10**test
array([ 10, 100])
```

If you want to use plain old tuples, you'll have to write the loop yourself:

```
>>> test = (1,2)
>>> tuple(10**k for k in test)
(10, 100)
```